# How to write Exif Data using custom Camera Class in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a custom camera application that is used to take pictures and crop them to square, now I want to know how to write Exif data for the final output image (specially the orientation)

Here are the important parts of my code:

```
captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Take a picture
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);                                
        }
    });
```

and this is the call back function:

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };
```

**Update:**
I Added the following to the onPictureTaken  method but nothing changed:

```
ExifInterface exif;
                exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
// Notice getOrientation method gets an Integer with the angle : 0 , 90 , 180 , 270 ..etc
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(getOrientation()) );
                exif.saveAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but I had similar issue so thought I'd fill this in first. 
If im right in understanding you are trying to store the angle in the .TAG_ORIENTATION exif attribute. That's incorrect, 
Adjust your 'getOrientation' method to give you one of the following Orientation Constants specific to the [ExifInterface class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ORIENTATION_NORMAL)

By putting in the specific angle the exif data will be incorrectly read by Image Viewers and how I read your question that is what you are doing.

> int   ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL  int    ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL
>   int   ORIENTATION_NORMAL   int    ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180
>   int   ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270   int    ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90
>   int   ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE    int    ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE
>   int   ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED